Sasl-suth issue with linux email server
I recently rebuilt my email server on Ubuntu 22.04, with postfix, amavis, clamav and virtual mailboxes with MariaSQL.
It also has roundcube for webaccess.
Everything is working fine with one exception: The Mail program on Widows 10 will not connect and SEND mail, but it can receive mail OK.
The immediate and most obvious solution to this is get rid of the absolutely rubbish Mail program on windows 10, the problem with this idea is this particular computer is used by an 84 year old, and teaching him how to use a new mail program will be problematical...
I've been looking in to this issue as much as I can, it seems my server is using STARTTLS and it does not look like the MAIL program will use this.
Another idea was to try allowing this laptop to send is on port 25, I can see a connection but the SASL-authentication is failing, even though I have the correct login credentials. The logs show SASL-AUTH is trying to authenticate using CRAM-MD5, but the passwords in the SQL DB are encrypted using Argon2 - which is I suspect why the authentication is failing.
Can I configure postfix to use SASL-AUTH with Argon2 cipher instead of the current CRAM-MD5 - or is this not possible?
Regards:
IcarusBop
